# Federal Reserve conditions

Tags: banking, money-supply, central-banking, federal-reserve

Does the Federal Reserve have conditions attached to the money that's created and distributed to major banks?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Economics StackExchange. Your question is somewhat ill-posed... I think the only answer to it would be, "Yes, those conditions are called 'banking regulation'." To understand why the question does not make much sense as it is, I would recommend looking into a short course on the economics of money and banking (there's first part of this from Kahn Academy looks like it might be okay: https://www.khanacademy.org/economics-finance-domain/core-finance/money-and-banking).

Comment: I've read more than my share of economic books on banking and the Federal Reserve. I recall reading in 'The Alchemists' that the Wall St. banks did not want capital injections due to the 'conditions' the Federal Reserve attached to it. Banking regulations did not prevent the Great Recession. What were those specific conditions that are not normally or legally binding?

Comment: That's a very different question! Consider editing your question to ask this instead.

Comment: Since you have added the reworded question separately, I've voted to close this one as a duplicate. You should also be able to close this question yourself.